# Using JavaScript to load form view in a modal, in Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I found a YouTube video that shows how to create a popup form using modal and JavaScript. I was able to achieve this for the button I have. However, I want to extend the same functionality to cover several buttons I have on the same view. I thought I could use the same JS code to achieve this but only the first button works and the subsequent buttons do not work. Only possible when I rewrite the JS code and change the `id` for each button; which to me is inefficient and introduces a lot of verbatim.

Again, after saving the form data in the modal popup, I want the view of the model to be loaded in the popup modal without redirecting the page to the page `controller/view`. I am not a guru in JavaScript but somehow I have a feeling that this is possible. Here is the link to the [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vq5zbnJZuEo).

***main.js File***

```
$(function() {
    // get the click of the create button
    $('#btnSeat1').click(function () {
        $('#modal').modal('show')
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).attr('value'));
    });
});
```

Below is the button initiating the event onclick and the modal

```
<?= Html::button('Book Now &raquo;', ['value' => Url::to('create'), 'class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'btnSeat1', 'schedule_id' => $model->schedule_id]) ?>

<?php
    Modal::begin([
        'header'=>'<h4>Book Seat</h4>',
        'id'=>'modal',
        'size'=>'modal-lg',
    ]);

    echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";

    Modal::end();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use class instead of id.

Change:

```
<?= Html::button('Book Now &raquo;', ['value' => Url::to('create'), 'class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'btnSeat1', 'schedule_id' => $model->schedule_id]) ?>
```

to something like:

```
<?= Html::button('Book Now &raquo;', ['value' => Url::to('create'), 'class' => 'btn btn-primary loadPopup', 'schedule_id' => $model->schedule_id]) ?>
```

Notice I've removed the `id` part and added class `loadPopup`.

Now the js:

```
$(function() {
    // get the click of the create button
    $('.loadPopup').click(function () {
        $('#modal').modal('show')
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).attr('value'));
    });
});
```

This handles all the clicks for the elements with class "loadPopup" that can be multiple while there can only be one element with specific id.

Comment: Thanks so much @Bizley. It is working well, you are a savior. Is it also possible to pass variables through the button in such a scenario? Like I am doing with `'schedule_id' => $model->schedule_id`. And how do I get the passed variable from the controller? If you can help me solve this, you will have saved me from so much!

Comment: If you want to pass something to js you can do it like with the `value` now (`$(this).attr('value')`), if you want to pass something to controller you can do it using GET method (adding more to the link in `Url::to()`). If you want to catch something coming from the controller you need to use something different from `.load()` js method - like `.post()`.

Comment: Okay, I had not seen that possibility of doing it via the `Url::to()`. Let me try with that first and see how it goes. Thanks for the insight.